# Application crash's upon click on EditText

Tags: android, kotlin

My application is crashing when click on EditText for typing. This is happens in Kotlin project. I found the cause of the crash i.e when I declare a Int var userId with default value -1. eg: `var userId: Int = -1` in the Activity containing EditText then application start crashing upon click on EditText. If change the var name or datatype or default then there is no crash.

Activity:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    var userId: Int = -1
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
}
```

Layout XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Sample application: https://github.com/47gurvinder/TestApplication.git

Crash Logs:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: net.rajpals.testapplication, PID: 21558
    com.android.internal.util.SyncResultReceiver$TimeoutException: Not called in 5000ms
        at com.android.internal.util.SyncResultReceiver.waitResult(SyncResultReceiver.java:56)
        at com.android.internal.util.SyncResultReceiver.getIntResult(SyncResultReceiver.java:68)
        at android.view.autofill.AutofillManager.ensureServiceClientAddedIfNeededLocked(AutofillManager.java:1841)
        at android.view.autofill.AutofillManager.notifyViewEnteredLocked(AutofillManager.java:958)
        at android.view.autofill.AutofillManager.notifyViewEntered(AutofillManager.java:942)
        at android.view.autofill.AutofillManager.notifyViewEntered(AutofillManager.java:899)
        at android.view.View.notifyEnterOrExitForAutoFillIfNeeded(View.java:7898)
        at android.view.View.onFocusChanged(View.java:7860)
        at android.widget.TextView.onFocusChanged(TextView.java:10816)
        at android.view.View.handleFocusGainInternal(View.java:7523)
        at android.view.View.requestFocusNoSearch(View.java:12494)
        at android.view.View.requestFocus(View.java:12468)
        at android.view.View.requestFocus(View.java:12435)
        at android.view.View.requestFocus(View.java:12377)
        at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:14876)
        at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:10875)
        at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:13484)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3088)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2781)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3088)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2781)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3088)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2781)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3088)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2781)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3088)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2781)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:3088)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2781)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:498)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1853)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:4059)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:69)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:456)
        at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:13745)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5637)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:5437)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4938)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4991)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4957)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:5097)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4965)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:5154)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4938)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4991)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4957)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4965)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4938)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7690)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:7659)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7620)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7820)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed the variable name to fix the Crash.

Solution:  `var userId: Long = -1`

Comment: It's either a solution or it's not. I removed the question from your solution.